# Add a custom page in Composite c1 version 2.1

Tags: c1-cms

I am working on a website which requires a functionality to import an excel spreadsheet. The admin of this website requires us to have a custom designed page in composite for him to simply select a excel sheet and upload.

Is there a way to build a custom page in c# and merge or add into composite ?

P.S - they are using composite version 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://docs.composite.net/Data/Adding-pages-with-Csharp there is a guide on adding pages to Composite C1 using C#.

But I suggest you handle this situation (dynamic content from an outside source, here an Excel sheet) using a C1 Function instead of generating a new page. Create the page like you normally would, but host a C1 Function on that page. Let this C1 Function generate what ever dynamic content is needed.

You can create C1 Functions using a wide variety of languages (ASP.NET UserControls, Razor, MVC, XSLT, raw C# that output html). Select the technology you are most comfortable with.

Relevant links:

- http://users.composite.net/Functions/GuideToC1Functions/What-is-a-C1-Function
- http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/Razor
- http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/Web-Forms
- http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/MVC
- http://docs.composite.net/XSLT/First-XSLT-Function
- http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/CSharpFunctions

Comment: Thanks mawtex for your answer but pardon me, I should have asked that how to add a custom admin page in composite c1. So just like we have admin pages for adding functions I would like to have a custom admin page for data import.

Thanks for your help once again

Comment: Just got something from Composite website itself

http://docs.composite.net/Console

Thanks mawtex for your answer.